# how to have sympy print exponential result in fraction form?

Tags: python, sympy

this code

```
x = symbols('x')
x**(1/2)
```

gives

[image]

how to have sympy print

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can "skirt" with the `l` symbol

`x**(l/2)`:

[image: screenshot)]